# php - how do I display items from an array with their values

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array ( [#LFC] => 1 [#cafc] => 2 [#SkySports] => 1)
```

How do i display it like this on a page? (preferably in value descending order as below):

```
\#cafc (2), #LFC (1), #SkySports (1)
```

Thanks

Comment: Based on your other questions before, have you actually took some time and read about arrays http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php and all the functions available http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, [sort the array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php)

```
arsort($arrayName);
```

Next, [iterate througth the array keys and values](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

```
foreach($arrayName as $key => $value)
{
    echo "$key ($value),";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [arsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) to sort by descending value and then looping through the array, printing key/value pairs, as follows:

```
arsort($original_array);
foreach($original_array as $k => $v) {
  echo $k.'('.$v.')';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i got your question right, use a [`foreach` loop](http://php.net/foreach) in combination with [`arsort`](http://php.net/arsort):

```
arsort($array);
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
  printf('%s (%s)',
    htmlspecialchars($k),
    htmlspecialchars($v));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arsort($array);
$output = array();
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
   $output[] = "$k ($v)";
}
print implode(", ", $output);
```

this will sort the array in reverse order, then create a new array with the data formatted the way you like, then implodes the output into a string separated by commas.  The other answers so far will leave a dangling comma.